# Current Source Output Stage

Tags: current, source

I'm developing a current source based on NPN Wilson modified current mirror. There's a restriction that cannot be used opamps, so i'm using only transistors. However, it's fundamental that doesn't appear voltage at the output if there is no load connected, so this is my question: how can I develop an output stage which doesn't produces voltage without load? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you sure that is the requirement? A true constant current stage should produce an infinite voltage with no load. It will be very difficult to design a circuit that produces zero voltage with no load because there would be no way that it could detect a load being connected so as to change to constant current mode. You need to clarify the requirements and also determine what constitutes "no load".

Comment: You should improve your question as Kevin suggested to encourage the best response, but I would imagine your goal is to have the current source shut down if a load is not present.  When operating without a load, the current source will increase voltage until the intended current flows.  If you determine your maximum intended load resistance, you can multiply it by your intended current to determine a maximum output voltage.  Simply shut down the converter if current drops to zero or voltage exceeds this value, and design the circuit to keep the converter off until intentionally restarted.

Comment: Kevin, I cannot upload the schematic, but the "no load" is when the circuit presents the condition open collector at the output transistor. 
I'm trying to make an electro stimulator, which output current is limited and the "no voltage" condition would be more safety.

Comment: K H, i'm trying to make an all analog circuit, so, I could make a current sensor at ouput to cutoff Vcc, but what could i do to indentify when there is load again?

Comment: You can pulse it periodically with a voltage or sine wave  and measure Vc/Ve=gain with a diode detector and decide if threshold represents no load then clamp base. Or use OCP and UCP together on Vc,Ve thus gain tells you if there is no,load.